# Using SharedPreferences with SQLiteOpenHelper before initialising the database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sharedpreferences

I would like to have a database for each user of my app. Usernames are stored in SharedPreferences. So I'm looking for something like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String LoggedInUser = sp.getString("user","");

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = LoggedInUser + ".db";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

But this doesn't work, because SharedPreferences need context (using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` doesn't work either. This can be solved by something like this:

```
private Context appContext;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.appContext = context;
}
```

And then accessing SharedPreferences afterwards.

But I need to access SharedPreferences before this method ("DATABASE_NAME" is used in the above method and I want to define "DATABASE_NAME" using SharedPreferences).

Is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since call to `super()` must be first statement, the only solution to achieve it would be to pass the `DATABASE_NAME` as constructor parameter:

```
public DatabaseHelper(final Context context, final string dbName) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 1);
 }
```

You can then either implement factory or Facade pattern to construct or pass the value to `DatabaseHelper` or simply pass the `dbName` value from Activity/Fragment.

An example of Factory could be:

```
public final class DatabaseFactory {

    public static DatabaseHelper getDataBaseHelper(final Context context){
        final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final String loggedInUser = sp.getString("user","");
        return new DatabaseHelper(context,loggedInUser);
    }
}
```

In Activity you can access the Helper as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        final DatabaseHelper myDB = DatabaseFactory.getDataBaseHelper(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I use a different java class for DatabaseFactory? Where is it being invoked? In your DatabaseHelper method, the third argument of `super` should be this Factory (instead of null)?

Comment: @LoMaPh `So I use a different java class for DatabaseFactory?` yes. `Where is it being invoked?` Its a static method, so whenever you need DatabaseHelper, use the static method to instantiate the `DatabaseHelper`.   `the third argument of super should be this Factory (instead of null)? ` No. `DatabaseFactory` is a standalone class. It follows the principle of composition rather than inheritance

Comment: Thanks. I added a java class for DatabaseFactory, but it has problem with `this`. It says `[package].DatabaseFactory.this cannot be references from a static context`. Also I really appreciate it if you rewrite my example with the required changes.

Comment: @LoMaPh don't initialize DatabaseFactory. Simply pass the `Context`

Comment: Thanks. By your post's edit, I guess you mean in those activities that I need to access database, instead of `final DatabaseHelper myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);` I need to write `final DatabaseHelper myDB = DatabaseFactory.getDataBaseHelper(this);`. But your last comment is not clear to me. I just made a new java class file and put your definition of DatabaseFactory class in it. And it has problem with the word `this` (erroe msg in my last comment).

Comment: @LoMaPh `I need to write final DatabaseHelper myDB = DatabaseFactory.getDataBaseHelper(this);` This is correct.  `And it has problem with the word this` are you calling this from Activity?

Comment: I made a new java class file for DatabaseFactory. I tried to extend `activity`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: My problem is where to put DatabaseFactory class definition. Does it need to be put in a separate java class file, or does it have to be added to all activities that want to access db, or it should be put in the DatabaseHelper file? I have put it in a separate file, but it has problem with `this`.

Comment: @LoMaPh Yes. Its needs to be in a separate java class file

Comment: @LoMaPh replace `this` with `context`

Answer (score 0):

Must you use SharedPreference in you SQLiteOpenHelper? 
I think you maybe use SQLite in your Activity, then how about declare SharedPreference in your Activity first, and get that in your SQLite through database's constructor.

Comment: I just need to access SharedPreferences to define the database name. Please give an example to clarify your proposed method